# How to configure APIs to run with Ropsten addresses

Tags: contract-development, ropsten, nodejs, aws

I have my contracts deployed on Ropsten network. I deployed those contracts from my local machine using [Truffle](https://truffleframework.com/) migrate.

Then I set up an AWS EC2 Ubuntu server to host my RESTful APIs. I installed web3js and node along with Node API code. At last I copied build folder to the server so that API can interact with the contracts.

I'm not able to configure my APIs to run with Ropsten contracts. How can I do that?

I'm actually looking for how and where do we give contract object reference in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [truffle-contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/truffle-contract) to have access to the contracts from a node application.

```
const TruffleContract = require("truffle-contract");
const MyContractArtifact = {
    abi: [],
    contractName: "MyContract",
};
const MyContract = TruffleContract(MyContractArtifact);
MyContract.setProvider(provider);
const deployed = await MyContract.deployed();
const result = await instance.someFunction(5);
```